# How to pass function in Queue in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel, queue, laravel-queue

I am using Laravel 5.4 queue. I would like to read Excel and make DB entry of that records after a few seconds.

```
$queue = Queue::later(10,'LogMsg', app('App\Http\Controllers\getFileController')->myfunc($name));
 return $queue;
```

This is my calling function, firstly can I pass like this?

```
public function myfunc($name)  {
    $f_data = Excel::load('public/invoices/'.$name, function($reader) {
        })->get();     
    if(!empty($f_data) && $f_data->count()){
           foreach ($f_data as $key => $row){                          
                  $inv = new final_tables;
                  foreach ($row as $key1 => $col){
                        $inv->$key1 = $row->$key1;
                  }
                  $inv->save();
           }
      }
     return 'done';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you really want to do is process an excel asynchronously and you can write a job class to do the same. The job class can be dispatched from the controller function and will run in the background.

An example job of the same functionality would look like:

```
class ReadExcelAndSaveRecordsToDB implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $filePath;

    /**
    * Create a new job instance.
    *
    * @return void
    */
   public function __construct(string $filePath)
   {
       $this->filePath = $filePath;
   }

   /**
    * Execute the job.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function handle()
    {
        $fileData = Excel::load($this->filePath, function($reader) {
        })->get();

        //Whatever you want to do with the file here, for eg. create a DB entry
        return 'done';
    }
}
```

Now you can dispatch the same job from your controller function like so:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;


public function someControllerAction(Request $request)
{
    $filePath = //Save file and obtain filepath

    $job = (new ReadExcelAndSaveRecordsToDB($filePath))
                ->delay(Carbon::now()->addMinutes(10));

    dispatch($job);
}
```

And that should do it for you.